# How to change the class of an element depending on the value on the JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file coming from python at the backend which is structured very basic like :

```
{"thing": "ok",
 "anotherthing": "fault"}
```

I am using a bootstrap span class badge. Now if the value in the JSON is "ok" then I want to display a green badge and if its "fault" then I want to display a red badge.

```
             <span>Thing</span>
             <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Operational</span>
             <span>AnotherThing</span>
             <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Major Fault</span>
```

Now the problem is how do I make it display a badge-success if on the backend the "fault" changes to "ok"? So basically its rendering the elements dynamically. I can display my whole JSON on HTML by doing `<span>{{message}}</span>`. This displays the JSON file. I probably need to use Javascript here but I have no clue on how to proceed. Also, doing ```{{message[0]}}" displays only "{" which is the starting of the string of JSON and not the first element which should be "thing".

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - Status Checker</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/styles.css') }}">
        <script> 
        const message = JSON.parse(message)

        const TestDrive = document.getElementById('TestDrive')
        if (message[0].TestDrive === 'OK') {
        TestDrive.classList.add('badge-success')
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <ul>
            <li>
             <span>TestDrive</span>
             <span id="TestDrive" class="badge badge-pill">Operational</span>
            </li>
</ul>

    

           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use message[0].thing

Comment: @deepak when `message[0]` returns `{` then `message` is a string and the parsed content would be an object. Your comment won't ever work with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse your JSON data which you are getting from python file in javascript.

const message = JSON.parse({{your_data_from_python_file}})

Here I assumed data will be array of object.
message[0] --> it will return you first element which is an object.
Use Dot notation to extract value from it.

```js
const message = [{
  "thing": "ok",
  "anotherthing": "fault"
}]
// get the thing's span using Id first
const first = document.getElementById('first')
if (message[0].thing === 'ok') {
  // now add class in thing's span
  first.classList.add('badge-success')
}

/*get the Anotherthing's span using Id second same is 
  present in html file*/
const second = document.getElementById('second')
if (message[0].anotherthing === 'fault') {
  second.classList.add('badge-danger')
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span>Thing</span>
<span id="first" class="badge badge-pill">Operational</span>

<span>AnotherThing</span>
<span id="second" class="badge badge-pill">Major Fault</span>
```

Comment: @Andreas thank you for pointing, I have corrected the same.

Comment: you need to pass that message in  your_data_from_python_file place.

Comment: ```
  <script> 
        const message = JSON.parse(message)

        const TestDrive = document.getElementById('TestDrive')
        if (message[0].TestDrive=== 'OK') {
        TestDrive.classList.add('badge-success')
        }

        </script>
```   I did pass it, still does not show badge on success

Comment: you are storing the ELEMENT Reference in 'TestDrive' but here you are assigning class to thing.classList.add. It should be TestDrive.classList.add

Comment: Yes, I had changed that but it still does not show the class for me :|

Comment: message[0].TestDrive  ->. message is an array of object.
when you do message[0] you will get first element.
first element is object having this structure { thing : ok , anotherthing: fault} 
and now to access the object property you need to use dot notation.
message[0].thing --> here thing is object property of first element.
Kindly console.log to check the structure of data after parsing using const message = JSON.parse({{message}}); console.log(message).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221203/discussion-between-deepak-and-snoogybunny).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

const message= {"thing": "ok",
 "anotherthing": "fault"};
const classList = message.thing==="ok" && "success" || "fault"
document.getElementById("TestDrive").classList.add(`badge-${classList}`);

</script>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `message' before initialization

Comment: That is the problem, when i try to parse message to JSON.parse, it gives 'message' is undefined